# Splunk format key value pair

Tags: java, splunk

I want to change my logger statements using key/value pair in such a way to be able to use it in splunk search. How can I retain the text `processOne` completed in the output log. Please advice.

```
log.info("ProcessOne completed for Run id  " + runId+ "...Time Taken(ms) + (System.currentTimeMillis() - tempTime));
```

I tried to change it in the way mentioned below, but I also want to add `ProcessOne` somewhere embedded inside this. How can I achieve it.

```
log.info("runId=%d, TimeTaken=%s", runId, (System.currentTimeMillis() - sTime_tds));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a message key?

Message="processone completed"

Or break up further into process and status e.g.

Process=processone
Status=completed